# Converting from base 10 beginner

Tags: javascript, radix

I was asked to write code that helps to go from base 10 to any other base. So far I have this

```
var y=23 //Number in base 10 I want to convert
var x=2 //Base I want to convert to 
var r=[]
if(y>=x){
r.push(y%x)
var y=(Math.floor(y/x))
}
else {
r.push(y)    
}
console.log(r)
```

Sorry if this is to basic i need to keep it simple thanks for the help

Comment: you can use `parseInt(string,base)` if this is not an assignment..Do you have to do it manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337419/how-do-you-convert-numbers-between-different-bases-in-javascript  (Google is your friend.)

Comment: numbers are in base 10 already, so use (123).toString(16) to get to base 16 (aka hex); or any base between 2 (binary) and 36 (a-z+\d)

Comment: can´t use parseInt(string,base) or .toString

Comment: Thanks Bob found an example that could help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code.

Comment: var p = 23; p.toString(2);

Comment: @BobBrown: note that you can flag questions that are the same as duplicates of the original question, which will also generate an automatic comment with the link for you. It also brings it to the attention of other users who can then close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use these codes:

```
var digits = [
  '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
  'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J',
  'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T',
  'U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
];

/**
 * x is the base, y is the decimal value
 * x must be in the range of 2..36
 * y must be greater than zero
 */
function base10ToBaseN(x,y) {
  var str = "";

  while (y>0) {
    var mod = y%x;
    var div = Math.floor(y/x);

    str = digits[mod]+str;
    y   = div;
  }

  return str;
}

alert(base10ToBaseN(2,23));
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/mLz5ycey

Comment: You don't need the `""` there since digits are already strings.

Comment: ah yeah! they r already strings

Comment: Rather than documenting it in a comment it's better to use the variable names: `base` and `number` - it allows you to delete the comment and as a bonus makes the code much more readable.

Comment: the OP is using these x,y variables :)

Comment: This fails where the number is 0 (it returns an empty string), consider changing the last line to something like `return str.length? str : '0';`. It also fails for negative numbers.

Comment: @RobG, i know, but i noted that in the comment before the function declaration

Comment: @JonDinham—it's pretty easy to fix though—store the sign and treat as +ve, then put the sign back at the end. I've given you the fix for the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToBase(input, base){
    var digits = [];
    while(digits.push(letter(input%base)), input = (input/base)|0)     //work for int
    function letter(n){ return n > 9 ? String.fromCharCode(n%base+55) : n;}
    return digits.reverse().join("");
}

convertToBase(255,16);        //FF
convertToBase(255,2);         //11111111
```

---

You can even attach this to the Number prototype for extra fun.

```
Number.prototype._ = function(b){ return convertToBase(this, b); };

255.._(16);       //FF
255.._(2);        //11111111
//Doesn't look like JavaScript's syntax anymore :)
```

However note that this only work for ∀n ∈ ℤ, n ≥ 0. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/nxf6wpkz/

---

> Why do mathematicians claim that Halloween is the same as Christmas?
>
> Because `convertToBase(25, 8)`.
>
> > Oct 31 = Dec 25

Comment: a short way of coding that is convertToBase=Function.call.bind((0).toString);

Comment: @dandavis - OP said `toString` cannot be used.

Comment: i see that, now. was wondering why we were re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: Regarding `+this`, given that the method is on *Number.prototype*, in what case would *this* not be a number? And even if its *this* is set to a string (using *call*, *apply* or *bind*), then  the internal operations convert it to a number anyway even if *input* and *base* are both strings (and *b* is not explicitly converted to a number anyway). :-)

Comment: @RobG - `this` cannot be a primitive, so it is never a number [primitive], which might cause problem if the number is 0, though `(input/base)|0` will probably change it to a real primitive.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫— *this* can be a primitive for built–in methods, e.g. `7..toString(2)` works just fine. In strict mode *this* can be any value for native functions too (but that's not relevant here).

Comment: @RobG - no, `this` can't be primitive anyhow. See this http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/sokpntwe/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫—it can be, hence [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2) says "*[Number.prototype.toString] throws a TypeError exception if its this value is not a Number or a Number object*", in other words, there is no compulsion for implementations to use a Number object for *this*, though they can if they wish.

Comment: @RobG - The spec also states that primitives are immutable, so no function can be attached to it. `this` is referring to the [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), and only objects can have properties. When `this` is set to a primitive, the value must be wrapped by an object to attach the function.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫— *this* is one parameter of an [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4). In strict mode, *this* doesn't have to be an object. Try your fiddle code in strict mode, it returns *number*. When a method is called on a primitive, what's the point of converting it to an object? It's only there to provide a value, so if converted to an object, it will just be turned back into a primitive (e.g. using *valueOf*). Hence built–ins are often happy with *this* as a primitive (e.g. `Number.prototype.toString.call(7, 2)`).

Comment: @RobG - True, but that only applies to strict mode (or maybe future ECMAScript versions.) Currently, without doing `"use strict"` there is no way to make `this` a type other than object. (I do agree that wrapping primitive with a wrapper object is very unnecessary. The first time I realized `this` cannot be a primitive sounded ridiculous to me.)