# Javascript Base Conversions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a line of code to convert base 10 numeric inputs to base 26 and vice versa, is anyone able to give me a formula or code to follow? JavaScript please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) both support a radix parameter.

- `(12345).toString(26)` returns `"i6l"`.
- `parseInt('i6l', 26)` returns `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

```
parseInt(string, radix)
```

You will get a better explanation on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337428/8077687