# How do I convert an integer in JavaScript to a 32bits?

Tags: javascript, bit

I have some numbers (base 10) that I want to convert to a 32 bits(base 2), I have tried a lot of things, I found out the **`>>>`** operator, but apparently it only converts negative numbers to a base 10 the equivalent of the 32 bits, instead of base 2

```
const number = 3

const bitNumber = 1 >>> 0

console.log(bitNumber) /// 1
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input and expected ouput?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a base 2 number type (as far as I know).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337419/how-do-you-convert-numbers-between-different-bases-in-javascript

Comment: All numbers can be expressed in whatever base you want, as strings.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are always stored as bits internally. It’s `console.log` that converts them to a string, and the string conversion uses decimal by default.

You can pass a base to [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
console.log(bitNumber.toString(2));
```

and display [as many bit positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) as you want:

```
console.log(bitNumber.toString(2).padStart(32, '0'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked nicely. I was thinking that JS had some method that  already transformed in 32 bit positions numbers, but padStart is the way